# iptables - How kill established connection except for an ip?

Tags: security, iptables

I've 2 iptables configuration. The second iptables replace the first at 15:00.
The first iptables is:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/iptables -F
/usr/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
/usr/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD DROP
/usr/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

csa=MY_IP_TO_ALLOW

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s $csa --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 1 -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s $csa --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 1 -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s $csa --dport 443 -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 1 -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MY_SECOND_IP --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The second iptables is:
#!/bin/bash

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -F
/usr/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
/usr/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD DROP
/usr/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MY_SECOND_IP  --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

When I switch from the first to the second iptables, how I'm sure that all alive connection will be killed from the ip saved in "csa"?

I'm not expert of iptables. Is this a secure way to protect from external ip? And is this the right way to block connection from ip allowed in first iptables when the second is actived?

Thank's a lot

Comment: I'm not an iptables expert but I think the proper way to do this would be with iptables-save and iptables-restore commands instead of the scripts you're using.
Also, when you're allowing INPUT traffic you should add RELATED as in iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
If you load an iptables configuration it should take effect immediately, meaning it will block established connections if they're not allowed in the new configuration. But you can easily test this by allowing a connection and then loading a configuration that blocks it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. use `iptables-restore`

   Adding rules one by one changes the firewall one rule at a time, with a possibly unwanted intermediate state for the firewall ruleset. By contrast, `iptables-save` atomically saves the ruleset, and the reverse `iptables-restore` atomically restores the ruleset (at least for a given table). A packet will either see the first ruleset, or see the second ruleset, but never an intermediate state.

   Once one have a working ruleset, one should not use shell commands to load it back, but instead use `iptables-save` to dump the rules in a file and `iptables-restore` to load them back from this file. This file can easily edited directly since it's the usual syntax at least for the rules themselves. If there are dynamic components (dynamic IPs, temporary IP bans etc.) one should adapt the rules with some logic, for example with user-defined chains or the companion [`ipset`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/) tool and associated [match](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#set) and [target](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#SET).
2. established connections will stay established with the current method

   Switching rules this way (or using `iptables-restore`) won't kill active connections because of the stateful short-circuiting rule. This rule queries *conntrack* which has still a valid entry and will continue allowing traffic. So the already established connection on port 22 80 or 443 is allowed to persist indefinitely (as long as adequate traffic persists) despite the new ruleset forbidding it now.

   To kill all established connections, one should in addition (install [*conntrack-tools*](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/conntrack-tools/downloads.html) and) run right after:

   ```
   conntrack -F
   ```

   which will flush the *conntrack* lookup table, requiring connections to come back through the NEW state. The rule for port 3306 will keep an already established connection unhindered there.
3. even `conntrack -F` is not enough with TCP by default.

   Already established TCP connections have a special treatment that validates their flow from TCP properties and allows to create again a *conntrack* entry in state NEW despite not seeing a TCP SYN packet. This is controlled by the *sysctl* property [`net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n113) which defaults to loose.

   This still requires to allow the NEW state somewhere in the *iptables* ruleset. Alas that's the case because the `OUTPUT` chain allows *everything* so this includes packets for flows in NEW state. So while packets from the client are now initially dropped, should the server emit *a single packet* from a previous flow to the client, the connection would resume unhindered.

   - To avoid this one could normally disable `netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose` like this:

     ```
     sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose=0
     ```

     but this would also disrupt the established connection to port 3306 after `conntrack -F`. *conntrack-tools* isn't easy to use to delete every flow except one, so using instead multiple `conntrack -D ...`  isn't an easy method, but is fine for OP's specific case (only three kind of flows to delete):

     Replace `conntrack -F` with:

     ```
     conntrack -D -s $csa -p tcp --dport 22
     conntrack -D -s $csa -p tcp --dport 80
     conntrack -D -s $csa -p tcp --dport 443
     ```
   - An other way is to keep the loose TCP handling but restrict outgoing packets with a stateful rule too.

     For example with (using the modern version of [`state`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#state): [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#conntrack)):

     ```
     iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
     iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
     iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
     ```

     One should in this case also enable explicit outgoing traffic for common services needed by the server  (DNS, NTP, Web access etc.) using rules like `-A OUTPUT -p ... --dport ... -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`).

---

Note: I left beside the handling of RELATED. It's usually a good idea to use RELATED along ESTABLISHED.

For example OP's rules don't allow ICMP, so without a RELATED rule to enable related ICMP errors, [Path MTU discovery  won't work properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems) (eg: TCP connections can hang when going through tunnels in the path). One should still have a look at this blog first: [Secure use of iptables and connection tracking helpers](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/).

Comment: Thank's a lot for your suggest! I've a last question. How can I switch from iptables1 to iptables 2 at certain hour? I've tought a script that at XX:XX change the rules. But what happens if at that time the system was rebooting? How can I check every minute that my iptables rule are right?

Comment: have a script that identifies what ruleset is present using a specific rules to check (and `iptables -C`). It can result in: 1/ no ruleset, 2/ 1st ruleset 3/ 2nd ruleset. Once it knows what ruleset is in place, it can choose depending on time what other to set. Conceptually That could be some kind of state matrix: given current state and time, what should be the target state (including "same state" which means "do nothing").

Comment: Also, there could be ways (but too complex to do an answer from your comment or mine) to use these iptables features all at once: iptables connmark/CONNMARK + mark/MARK + time match module to have a static iptables ruleset that would handle everything. The difficult part is to avoid having to run conntrack and use a mark instead to memorize if the packet (from the flow) is from a previous state or not. If it worked, it would still require external handling for daylight saving time.

Comment: I've problem to kill established connection yet. I've tried to execute:
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose=0
conntrack -F
but connection on the 5060:5070 and 10000:20000 ports are still alive and connected to the server.
Is there a way to kill them?

Comment: None of your rulesets allow such connections: it doesn't fit the ruleset in your question, so these connections should never have existed in the first place. If you change the premises, this would require a new question.

Comment: Also: if no packet is emitted, nothing will change: established connections can't be killed with iptables without activity and without a REJECT rule, they can just be forbidden to work. But this doesn't change the fact that your ruleset doesn't ever allow these connections in the first place. It looks like my answer isn't complete about killing a connection, but the question isn't complete either because you are talking about unrelated ports.

Comment: I should thus probably delete this answer because incomplete (until I get better), but can't because it's the accepted answer. You can remove the accepted answer tag if needed